# Ansible - Concatenate list of items for command module without surrounding quotes

Tags: list, shell, ansible

I'm trying to concatentate an Ansible list into a space seperate string without surrounding quotes within a shell or command module call.

The command I'm trying to use requires a space separated list of variables only.

So with the list:

```
somelist:
    - item1
    - item2
```

We can build the shell module task:

```
- name: Execute a command
  ansible.builtin.shell: >
    /some/command {{ somelist | split(' ') }}
```

Which translates on the actual command to:

```
/some/command 'item1 item2'
```

However, the command in question requires a space separated list of variables, not a string - such as:

```
/some/command item1 item2
```

I could use loop but that produces a list of dictionaries in the captured results which I then can't use as a conditional for the when: clause on the task.

Is there some way to convert the Ansible list to the above format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *We can build the shell module task:*
>
> ```yaml
> - name: Execute a command
>   ansible.builtin.shell: >
>     /some/command {{ somelist | split(' ') }}
> ```
>
> *Which translates on the actual command to:*
>
> ```yaml
> /some/command 'item1 item2'
> ```

Actually no. A simple test would just fail with

```yaml
TASK [Execute a command] ******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    Unexpected templating type error occurred on (/some/command {{ somelist | split(' ') }}
    ): descriptor 'split' requires a 'unicode' object but received a 'list'
```

---

In order to concatenate a list of items one will need to `join` them.

A  minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    somelist:
      - item1
      - item2

  tasks:

  - shell:
      cmd: "echo {{ somelist | join(' ') }}"
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
    changed: true
    cmd: echo item1 item2
    delta: '0:00:00.013335'
    end: '2023-11-23 12:30:00.013334'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2023-11-23 12:30:00.000000'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: item1 item2
    stdout_lines:
    - item1 item2
```

**Documentation Example**

- [Manipulating strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings)

  > *To concatenate a list into a string:*
  >
  > *`{{ list | join(" ") }}`*

Comment: Thank you! I was using the wrong function entirely - much appreciated.